# NSAttributedString invalid for autoresizing exception

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.2

I am trying to use `NSAttributed` String to display in the `UILabel`, and I am using word wrap as line break mode.
But when I run the app, it throws exception "`NSAttributedString invalid for autoresizing, it must have a single spanning paragraph style (or none) with a non-wrapping lineBreakMode.`"

Can someone suggest me how to resolve this?

Comment: could you show your code?

Comment: <blink>NSMutableDictionary *a = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [a setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName];
   
    
    NSMutableAttributedString *b = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"abcd" attributes:b];
    self.label.attributedText = b;

Comment: why you adding b as attribute to itself?

Comment: `NSMutableAttributedString *b = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"abcd" attributes:a]; ` did it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `NSMutableAttributedString` in wrong way I assume, it should be used as under,

```
NSMutableDictionary *a = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[a setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName]; 
NSMutableAttributedString *b = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"abcd" attributes:a]; 
self.label.attributedText = b;
```

after trying the above code, you should get the UILabel output like I have showed in image [image]

but if you want to set the attribute  separately then you should do like this

```
[b addAttribute:ATTRIBUTENAME value:VALUE range:RANGE];
```

for example setting attribute for background color

```
[str addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:NSMakeRange(2,4)];
```

Comment: But during initializing the attributed string itself, i am setting the attributes , "NSMutableAttributedString ab = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"kkkk" attributes:a]"

Comment: yes, it should work, I have just tested on my Xcode, it works fine, you might have some other issue.  it works with **Word Wrap** mode also.

Comment: But still i took your suggestion and tried it, it still throws exception

Comment: could you post your screen shot where you setting the property? are you sure you are connecting the Outlet properly with Label?

Comment: check out my updated answer, i added the screen shot of output, you are not getting this?

Comment: yes, same code i have and i have set the word wrap as line break mode in xib, it crashes. But it works fine if i have truncate tail.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25234/discussion-between-nsgulliver-and-kbpro)

Comment: no, but i figured out its crashing when i set the autoshrink to minimum font size. If i change it to fixed font size it works properly. So now trying to figure out how to set the minimum font size for the NSAttributed string.

Comment: alright, so problem was not here as i said, it is some other properties you were changing, anyways if you find my help useful then you could accept the answer

Comment: but i am afraid shrinking is not your problem as well, I have used shrinking to minimum font size and it works perfect

Answer (score 8):

To fix, set:

```
[yourLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:NO];
```

just make sure you don't override this later on in your code ;)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who see this question. What helped me was disabling the resize of the `UILabel`'s text. On my code I had this:

```
[myLabel setAdjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth:YES];
[myLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
[myLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:15.0/myLabel.font.pointSize];
```

Removed it and started to work.